# Rails - Ordering records by model method result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the User model with the following method:

```
def like_dislike_proportion
  self.likes.to_f / self.dislikes.to_f
end
```

Where self.likes and self.dislikes both return an Integer. I want to make a ranking with the top 10 users with the biggest like/dislike proportion, and the bottom 10, with the lowest proportion.

I tried using

```
User.order('like_dislike_proportion DESC').limit(10)
```

But it doesn't work, because the like_dislike_proportion is not a persistent attribute in the database.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ranking = User.all.map { |u| 
    {name: u.name, proportion: (u.likes.to_f/u.dislikes.to_f)} 
}.sort_by { |r| r[:proportion] }
```